# Closing a Vuetify menu when child dialog opens

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify data table where each row has a menu containing a number of options which open a dialog.  When the dialog opens the parent v-menu remains open but I would like this to close.

I've looked for a way to close this programatically and have tried the *close-on-content-click* prop but this doesn't seem to work once the menu button click event takes place.

Below is an example of the v-data-table code I'm using, with a live demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-data-table-filtering-fzyxf

```
<template>
  <!-- data table -->
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" item-key="name" class="elevation-1 pa-6">
    <!-- row name slot -->
    <template v-slot:item.name="{item}">{{item.name}}</template>

    <!-- row actions slot -->
    <template v-slot:item.actions="{item}">
      <!-- row menu -->
      <v-menu>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn text v-on="on">open menu</v-btn>
        </template>

        <!-- menu items -->
        <v-list>
          <!-- menu item 1 -->
          <v-list-item>
            <template>
              <div>
                <!-- dialog for menu item 1 -->
                <v-dialog v-model="menu1">
                  <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
                    <v-btn text v-on="on">action 1</v-btn>
                  </template>

                  <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>Action 1</v-card-title>
                  </v-card>
                </v-dialog>
              </div>
            </template>
          </v-list-item>

          <!-- menu item 2 -->
          <v-list-item>
            <template>
              <div>
                <!-- dialog for menu item 2 -->
                <v-dialog v-model="menu2">
                  <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
                    <v-btn text v-on="on">action 2</v-btn>
                  </template>

                  <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>Action 2</v-card-title>
                  </v-card>
                </v-dialog>
              </div>
            </template>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

I thought there might be a way to reference each menu but haven't managed to work that out yet.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create two functions that can toggle menus

```
toggleMenu1() { menu1 = !menu1 },
toggleMenu2() { menu2 = !menu2 },
```

and call those functions in v-btn's via @click.stop event

```
<v-btn text v-on="on" @click.stop="toggleMenu1()">action 1</v-btn>
```

should have resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).